# Send coins from bitcoind full node to lnd without fee?

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network, network

I'm trying to fund my LND node, for that I put some dust on my BTC wallet address and now I want to send to my LND wallet address but when I try to send with fees "paytxfee": 0.00000000 returns an error saying:

> Error: This transaction requires a transaction fee of at least
>   0.00012192

So I'm wondering if there's a way to reduce this fee or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lnd node contains a regular Bitcoin wallet. In order to open a channel you currently need to do on chain transactions (which obviously require fees)

1. You need to send Bitcoins to your lnd wallet
2. You need to open a channel which is another on chain transaction.

Theoretically the first tx could be omitted if lnd would support the import of other private keys (I think no lightning wallet currently does this as it seems to be of lower priority at this time)

Also you could ask Simone to open a channel with you and use loop or a submarine swap to get your channel refilled in exchange for you sending your btc onchain. In that case it is still 2 tx but only one for which you pay on chain fees. The onchain fees for Opening the channel are paid by your channel partner.

Comment: I see, reading about lightning I realized that there's no way of getting rid of these fees, it is part of the strength of the BTC protocol, thanks!

Comment: Yeah everything is backed by Bitcoin transactions at the end. The trustless properties of lightning are actually trusting in the Bitcoin blockchain and only trustless because Bitcoin is.